# Where does the access-control-allow-origin header go

Tags: http, cors

This is a trivial question, I know, but I just can't figure it out properly.

I have a website `http://a.com` that references a script from `http://b.com/script.js` . Where should I put the `access-control-allow-origin` header - on `a.com` or on `b.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers follow the rule of "same origin".

It means a page loaded from **a.com:80** can only access resources from **a.com:80**

If the browser wants to load a resource from **b.com:443** in an html document provided by **a.com:80** it must be explicitly allowed by **a.com:80**

To answer, the html document(s) returned by **a.com:80** must include the following header

> access-control-allow-origin=b.com:443

to allow the browser to load something from **b.com:443**